# Methods to hex edit binary files via Powershell

Tags: powershell, binary, hex, patch, bytestream

I am trying to perform a binary hex edit from the command line using only PowerShell. I have had partial success performing a hex replace with this snippet. My problem arises when `123456` occurs multiple times, since the replacement was only supposed to take place at a specific location.

> ***Note:*** This snippet requires the `Convert-ByteArrayToHexString` and `Convert-HexStringToByteArray` functions shown [here](https://www.sans.org/blog/powershell-byte-array-and-hex-functions/).

```
$readin = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\OldFile.exe");
$hx = Convert-ByteArrayToHexString $readin -Width 40 -Delimiter "";
$hx = $hx -replace "123456","FFFFFF";
$hx = "0x" + $hx;
$writeout = Convert-HexStringToByteArray $hx;
Set-Content -Value $writeout -Encoding byte -Path "C:\NewFile.exe";
```

How can I specify an offset position into PowerShell rather than use this sketchy `-replace` command?

Comment: There are a lot of good answers here, but very few arrive at the door. It would have been great to see a function that takes: (1) a filename, (2) a *hex-string* to search for, **or** (3) an offset, (4) a hex-string to replace with, as input to some powershell function. I guess we'll have to wait...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You already have a byte array, so you could simply modify the bytes at any given offset.

```
$bytes  = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\OldFile.exe")
$offset = 23

$bytes[$offset]   = 0xFF
$bytes[$offset+1] = 0xFF
$bytes[$offset+2] = 0xFF

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\NewFile.exe", $bytes)
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can we specify an offset position into PowerShell to replace this sketchy `-replace` command.

[Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20935550/45375) addresses the offset question, and [brianary's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725589/45375) shows a more PowerShell-idiomatic variant.

That said, it sounds like if you had a solution for replacing only the *first* occurrence of your search string, your original solution may work.

---

#### First-occurrence-only string replacement:

Unfortunately, **neither PowerShell's `-replace` operator nor .NET's `String.Replace()` method offer limiting replacing to *one* occurrence (or a fixed number)**.

However, there is a **workaround**:

```
$hx = $hx -replace '(?s)123456(.*)', 'FFFFFF$1'
```

- `(?s)`is an inline regex option that makes regex metacharacter `.` match *newlines* too.
- `(.*)` captures all *remaining* characters in capture group 1, and `$1` in the replacement string references them, which effectively removes just the *first* occurrence. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for the more information about `-replace` and the syntax of the replacement operand.)
- General caveats:

  - If your *search string* happens to contain regex metacharacters that you want to be taken literally, `\`-escape them individually or, more generally, pass the entire search term to `[regex]::Escape()`.
  - If your *replacement string* happens to contain `$` characters that you want to be taken literally, `$`-escape them or, more generally, apply `-replace '\$', '$$$$'` (sic) to it.

However, as [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) points out, while the above generically solves the replace-only-once problem, it is ***not a fully robust solution*, because there is no guarantee that the search string will match at a *byte boundary***; e.g., single-byte search string `12` would match the middle `12` in `0123`, even though there is no *byte* `12` in the input string, composed of bytes `01` and `23`.

To address this ambiguity, the input "byte string" and the search string must be constructed differently: simply **separate the digits constituting a byte each with spaces**, as shown below.

---

#### Replacing byte sequences by *search* rather than fixed offsets:

Here's **an all-PowerShell solution** (PSv4+) that doesn't require third-party functionality:

Note:

- As in your attempt, the entire file contents are read at once, and to-and- from string conversion is performed; PSv4+ syntax
- To construct the *search and replacement strings* as "byte strings" with space-separated hex. representations created from byte-array input, use the same approach as for constructing the byte string from the *input* as shown below, e.g.:

  - `(0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x1).ForEach('ToString', 'X') -join ' '` -> `'12 34 56 1'`

    - `.ForEach('ToString', 'X')` is the equivalent of calling `.ToString('X')` on each array element and collecting the results.
  - If prefer each byte to be consistently represented as *two* hex digits, even for values less than `0x10`, (e.g., `01` rather than `1`), use `'X2'`, which increases memory consumption, however.
    Also, you'll have to `0`-prefix single-digit byte values in the search string too, e.g.:
    `'12 34 56 01'`

```
# Read the entire file content as a [byte[]] array.
# Note: Use PowerShell *Core* syntax. 
# In *Windows PowerShell*, replace `-AsByteStream` with `-Encoding Byte`
# `-Raw` ensures that the file is efficiently read as [byte[]] array at once.
$byteArray = Get-Content C:\OldFile.exe -Raw -AsByteStream

# Convert the byte array to a single-line "byte string", 
# where the whitespace-separated tokens are the hex. encoding of a single byte.
# If you want to guaranteed that even byte values < 0x10 are represented as
# *pairs* of hex digits, use 'X2' instead.
$byteString = $byteArray.ForEach('ToString', 'X') -join ' '

# Perform the replacement.
# Note that since the string is guaranteed to be single-line, 
# inline option `(?s)` isn't needed.
# Also note how the hex-digit sequences representing bytes are also separated
# by spaces in the search and replacement strings.
$byteString = $byteString -replace '\b12 34 56\b(.*)', 'FF FF FF$1'

# Convert the byte string back to a [byte[]] array, and save it to the
# target file.
# Note how the array is passed as an *argument*, via parameter -Value, 
# rather than via the pipeline, because that is much faster.
# Again, in *Windows PowerShell* use `-Encoding Byte` instead of `-AsByteStream`.
[byte[]] $newByteArray = -split $byteString -replace '^', '0x'
Set-Content "C:\NewFile.exe" -AsByteStream -Value $newByteArray
```

Comment: The method posted over here, *closed for being a duplicate*, is faster and uses less memroy.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336893/use-powershell-to-find-and-replace-hex-values-in-binary-files

Comment: @js2010: I assume you're referring to your own answer there: (a) the question is still a duplicate and (b) your answer shows how to replace a _single_ byte value, _however often it appears_ in the file (whereas the original question was completely open-ended). I suggest you recreate your answer here and amend it to meet this question's specific requirements, pointing out that dealing with _decimal_ values allows for a shorter and more efficient solution. If you also add `-Raw` to the `Get-Content` call and fix the clumsy `-as 'byte[]'`, you'll have my up-vote.

Comment: Not my answer, the one given who first asked the question.

Comment: @js2010: It is never appropriate to edit an _answer_ into a _question_. If you feel that there's something noteworthy there (which isn't obvious to me at first glance, given the very specific CSV-based code in there, and the fact that the whole file is still read into memory, along with inefficient pipeline-based code, and an explicit warning about memory use), encourage the author to post an _answer_, preferably _here_.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can oversee the quest, there is no need to do any hexadecimal conversion on a byte stream to do a replacement. You can just do a replacement on a decimal value list (default string conversion) where the values are bounded by spaces (word ends), e.g.:
<sub>(I am skipping the file input/output which is already explained in the [answer from @mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342311/1701026))</sub>

```
$bInput = [Byte[]](0x69, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x57, 0x61, 0x73, 0x48, 0x65, 0x72, 0x65)
$bOriginal = [Byte[]](0x57, 0x61, 0x73, 0x48)
$bSubstitute = [Byte[]](0x20, 0x77, 0x61, 0x73, 0x20, 0x68)
```

> ```
> $bOutput = [Byte[]]("$bInput" -Replace "\b$bOriginal\b", "$bSubstitute" -Split '\s+')
> ```

<sub>In case you like to use hexadecimal strings (e.g. for the replace arguments), you can convert a hex string to a byte array as follows: `[Byte[]]('123456' -Split '(..)' | ? { $_ } | % {[Convert]::toint16($_, 16)})`</sub>

Note that this solution supports different `$bOriginal` and `$bSubstitute` lengths. In such a case, if you like to start replacing from a specific offset you might want to use the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet:

```
$Offset = 3
$bArray = $bInput | Select -Skip $Offset
$bArray = [Byte[]]("$bArray" -Replace "\b$bOriginal\b", "$bSubstitute" -Split '\s+')
$bOutput = ($bInput | Select -First $Offset) + $bArray
```

Comment: +1 for the clever implicit (decimal) stringification; it results in a larger string, but that probably won't matter.
Do note, however, that the use of `-replace` still bears the risk of unintentionally replacing _multiple_ occurrences - which was the OP's initial problem (though not the only one, due to the byte-boundary issues you pointed out).
Also, instead of `Select-Object` I'd use array slicing, because that will make a noticeable difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the way most idiomatic to PowerShell would be:

```
$offset = 0x3C
[byte[]]$bytes = Get-Content C:\OldFile.exe -Encoding Byte -Raw

$bytes[$offset++] = 0xFF
$bytes[$offset++] = 0xFF
$bytes[$offset] = 0xFF

,$bytes |Set-Content C:\NewFile.exe -Encoding Byte
```