# How to make hex file exact same size with the edited one

Tags: file, hex, hexdump

I have edit some hex values in a file .rpf in HxD, after I finish editing the edited file reduced 5 bytes (no line or value is removed just edited 1F 23 0B AS to U1 45 BD 37)
Is there anyway I could the edited file exactly same size as the original ?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with HxD, but if it's anything like other hex editors, this suggests a User Error more than anything else. Hex editors are not supposed to add or remove bytes (unless instructed to do so). BTW, both input and output strings do not look like any hex I'm familiar with.

Comment: `1F 23 0B AS` .. `S` is not a valid HEX value .. `U1 45 BD 37` .. `U` is also not a valid HEX value. I regularly use HxD, how are you editing your file?

Comment: might be done from powershell - see ansgar's answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935356/methods-to-hex-edit-binary-files-via-powershell