# How to convert Hex string with address and ASCII values to binary file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, hex, binaryfiles, bin

I have a file with this content:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 2D 13 2D 13 00 00 00 00   ........-.-.....
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
```

I would like to create .bin file with with content.
I tried this way:

```
$bytes = [byte]0xFF 
Set-Content -Path .\content.bin -Value $bytes -Encoding Byte
```

It created the bin file but when I try to check the hex with this way:

```
Format-Hex .\content.bin
```

It return this output:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   FF
```

My expectation result supposed to be like this:

```
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 2D 13 2D 13 00 00 00 00   ........-.-.....
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
```

Anyone can give idea please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this a question of how `Format-Hex` shows the bytes on screen?

Comment: Nope, I want to convert the hex to .bin file. I use Format-Hex to make sure the .bin file is correct or not @Theo

Comment: So to get this straight, you have a text dump showing the bin file as formatted hex characters and now you want to convert that back into a binary file? Then why bother with Format-Hex at all, because that does the exact opposite..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your comment *I want to convert the hex to .bin file*.

There are many applications that can do a hexdump of a binary file. PowerShell has the [Format-Hex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex) cmdlet for that, but it doesn't create output as you show in your question.
Format-Hex starts with a byte count header line

`00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F`

then an empty line and after that the hex data.
It also adds a byte counter left margin before the actual data.

Your example doesnt do that, but instead adds a hyphen in between every eight bytes,  so it is obviously not created using Format-Hex.

Anyway, here's how you can recreate a binary file from both types of hexdump output:

```
$inputFile  = 'D:\Test\yourHexdump.txt'
$outputFile = 'D:\Test\yourBinaryFile.bin'  # use absolute full path here
# if the output file already exists, delete it
if (Test-Path -Path $outputFile -PathType Leaf) { Remove-Item -Path $outputFile -Force }

# create a FileStream object to write the converted bytes to file
$stream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($outputFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Append, [IO.FileAccess]::Write)

# now loop through the file line-by-line and parse out the bytes
switch -Regex -File $inputFile {
    # if this is from Format-Hex output, ignore the 1-16 byte header and empty line(s)
    '^\s+00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F|^\s*$' {}  
    default { 
        # if this is from Format-Hex output, remove the byte counters in the left margin
        $line = if ($_ -match '^[0-9A-f]{8}\s') { $_.Substring(8) } else { $_ }
        # convert the hex values into an array of bytes
        [byte[]]$bytes = (($line.TrimStart() -split '\s{2,}')[0].Trim() -replace '-' -split '\s+' -ne '' -replace '^', '0X')
        # write to file
        $stream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Count)
    }
}
# dispose of the stream
$stream.Flush()     # probably Dispose() also flushes..
$stream.Dispose()
```